# C# - How can i wrap a static class

Tags: c#, inheritance, word-wrap

I want to make util classes for System.Io (such as File, Directory etc).

Since inheritance cannot be done for static classes i want to know how would be a proper way to wrap lets say System.Io.File.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want something more than "write your (presumably static) utility class and methods" ? Other than that it is very hard to answer without more context of what you are trying to do...

Comment: Wouldn't extension methods work?

Comment: I think what he wants to do is to add methods to an existing static class, and no, extension methods don't work in this case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would create three types:

- An interface containing all the methods you want to be able to test etc, e.g.

  ```
  public interface IFileSystem
  {
      Stream OpenWrite(string filename);
      TextReader OpenText(string filename);
      // etc
  }
  ```
- An implementation which delegates to the system implementation:

  ```
  public class FrameworkFileSystem : IFileSystem
  {
      public Stream OpenWrite(string filename)
      {
          return File.OpenWrite(filename);
      }
      // etc
  }
  ```
- A fake implementation for testing:

  ```
  public class FakeFileSystem : IFileSystem
  {
      // Probably all kinds of things to allow in-memory files
      // to be created etc
  }
  ```

You may well not want to put *everything* from `File` in there though - as many of the operations can be composed from the "core" ones. Of course, that would mean reimplementing the operations yourself, which may be undesirable...